# RHEL Unable to install any package using yum

Tags: yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

I am pretty new to Linux and  trying to install a package using yum in RHEL5 linux. Even the simplest of the simple packages I am not able to install and it looks like naming server issue. I tried changing name server to googles as in /etc/resolv.conf  file to

```
\\; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search compute-1.internal
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Even when I am trying to wget a file also I am getting the following error

wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
--2012-12-03 14:45:14--  http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
Resolving pkgs.repoforge.org... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address `pkgs.repoforge.org'

Even the directy Yum installs are also failing for the same reason

```
root@domU-12-31-39-10-09-BD x11vnc-0.9.14]# yum install whoami
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, fastestmirror, rhui-lb, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rhui-us-east-client-config-server-5: rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com
 * rhui-us-east-rhel-server: rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com
https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/5/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/5/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/5/5Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
Trying other mirror.
```

If anyone can help me on 
1) How to change the default yum repository to a different one, something like rpmforge
2) How can I resolve this name or service unknown error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you resolve other URLs?

Comment: What happens when you ping google.com? I'm convinced that your DNS is not resolving. Is this an AWS instance? Otherwise, why do you have search compute-1.internal in there? I would removed the search line, and add in google's secondary DNS after the primary. It is 8.8.4.4.

Comment: @terdon I can't resolve any of the URLs

Comment: You are off topic, this has nothing to do with yum. Please configure your network properly before starting yum installs. You need a DNS, try one from openDNS. `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`